# What is the difference between "login" and "attempt" method in Auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm learning Laravel 5.4 and customizing and making my original Auth functionalities.

The below is my "authenticate" method.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $remember_me = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
    Auth::guard('web');
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => trim($request->input('username')),
        'password' => trim($request->input('password'))
    );
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember_me)){
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->user();
        Auth::guard('web')->login($user, $remember_me);
        return redirect()->route('mypage');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have a question about the part of $remember_me argument about both attempt and login methods noted above.

What is the difference between them?

When I saw the documentation, it said similar to, if you want to make "remember me" token, you can set the second boolean argument about both of them.

Answer (score 12):

`attempt($credentials, $remember_me)` will attempt to log the user in if the login credentials are correct. If they are not, then the user is not logged in. This method returns a boolean so you can check success.

`login($user_id, $remember_me)` will log the user in, without checking any credentials.

The remember me specifys if the user login should persist across browser sessions without needing to re-auth.

In your example I see your calling `login(...)` within your `attempt(...)`. This shouldn't be needed. You can remove the `login(...)` line.

Example:

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember_me)){
    return redirect()->route('mypage');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering with an example.
I understand the differences between the both.

In your comment, "This should be needed.". It is "This shouldn't be needed." isn't it?

Anyway, thank you very much!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand about your comment  "This should be needed".
But I understand now.

Thank you !!

Comment: Fixed typo. Meant to be shouldn't.